# Orthonormal basis with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I have the set : $$W=[(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in{\mathbb{R}^4}\quad| \quad x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4=0]$$

I need to find orthonormal basis, So I found just one vector and I have only parameters in my answer and I am not sure that what suppose to be.
I found the vector $$\vec\epsilon_1= \frac{1}{\sqrt(x_2+x_3+x_4)^2 +x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}(x_2+x_3+x_4,x_2,x_3,x_4)$$

My question is,  should I get an answer with numbers?

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to get an answer with numbers.

Comment: Given that you are confused as to what the answer is supposed to look like, it seems as though you have misunderstood some definition.  Do you understand what a basis of a subspace is? Do you understand the difference between a basis and an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** To begin, find *any* basis for $W$. If you want to do so by using a familiar technique, it might be helpful to note that $W$ is the kernel/nullspace of the matrix $A = \pmatrix{1&-1&-1&-1}$.  Once you have a basis, you can apply the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to produce an orthonormal basis of $W$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you completely, your meaning is that I can take any $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ according to the equation I have been given and then use gram schmidt procces?

Comment: @Sagigever do you understand what a "basis" of a subspace is?

Comment: yes, I understand what is mean

Comment: @Sagigever So if the question was only to find a "basis" (instead of an "orthonormal basis") of $W$, would you be able to answer this question?

Comment: @Sagigever I don't really know how to respond to your first comment directly because I don't know what you mean by "take any $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ according to the equation" and apply the Gram Schmidt process. It does not make sense (for this problem) to apply the Gram Schmidt process to only one vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$

Comment: Ok now I think what you have meant to, so actually I need to work with a basis for this subspace?  for example $(1,1,0,0) , (1,0,1,0), (1,0,0,1)$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now apply the Gram Schmidt process to this basis.